# Is there any way to mock this function with Jasmine or Sinon?

Tags: node.js, mocking

I'm testing a module, and I want to mock out a a dependency within that module. Let me frame my scenario, if I may:

*In my module*

```
myModule.prototype.func = function(callback) {
    complexObj.doStuff('foo', function(err) {
        callback(err, 'stuff');
    });
};
```

So, I'm trying to basically mock `complexObj`. It doesn't really matter if I mock the entire object or just the `doStuff` function in this case. Let's assume that `doStuff` does something like interact with a web service or the filesystem. `complexObj` is being injected into `myModule` by dependency injection. I've been using Jasmine and Sinon to try to mock or stub this object and function, but I've had no luck, so I've resorted to something like this, which seems a little kludgy:

*In my spec:*

```
describe('Testing myModule', function() {
    it('should do stuff', function() {
        ComplexObj.prototype.doStuff = function(arg, callback) {
            callback(null); // If no errors, 'doStuff' returns null indicating no errors
        };

        var complexObj = new ComplexObj();

        new myModule(complexObj).func(function(err, results) {
            // Set up expectations...
        });
    });
});
```

So, as you can see, I'm *psuedo*-mocking out the `doStuff` function in the `ComplexObj` object. Since I'm not concerned about `ComplexObj` or `doStuff` function, I'm just invoking the callback with 'null' indicating to `func` that there were no errors in `doStuff`. As I mentioned before, I feel there should be a better way to handle this? Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Jasmine, you would do something like this:

```
var complexObj = {doStuff: null};
spyOn(complexObj, 'doStuff');
new myModule(complexObj).func(function(err, results) {
    expect(complexObj.doStuff).toHaveBeenCalledWith(args, callback);
});
```

**Edit:** Or you could set up expectations in your mocked `doStuff`:

```
var complexObj = {doStuff: null};
spyOn(complexObj, 'doStuff').andCallFake(function(args, callback) {
    expect(args).toEqual(/*...*/);
    expect(callback).toEqual(/*...*/);
    callback();
});
new myModule(complexObj).func(function(err, results) {
    expect(complexObj.doStuff).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: Is it best practice to `expect` in a mock fake? I would assume that the expectation not getting executed because `doStuff` is never called, would result in false assumptions. I tend to set vars in fake and expect stuff on that vars after calling the function.